# How to disable TLS1.3 in openSSl 1.1.1

Tags: openssl, tls1.2

I have updated my openssl from 1.1.0 to 1.1.1 recently. Openssl 1.1.1 version supports TLS1.3 feature.

But i want to use TLS 1.2 only for my application with curl 7.58 in Ubuntu 18.04. So **while using openssl 1.1.1 how to disable default TLS 1.3 and how to enable TLS 1.2**?

Can i set any flags while building openssl 1.1.1 to disable TLS 1.3 or can i get any package from ubuntu to disable TLS 1.3

Comment: You haven't told us at all what your application is, or how it interfaces to OpenSSL. In general, you need to set TLS options.

Answer (score 0):

For curl, you can use **--tls-max 1.2** if your Ubuntu supports it.

Comment: Do you know to do it system-wide (e.g. edit `openssl.cnf`)?